# Are bitset individual bits thread safe for per individual thread to write into at a single time?

Tags: c++, c++11, concurrency, bitset

I wonder if we operate on a [catchline](https://youtu.be/tNkVUIv2gEE?t=3960) or even 64bit word sizes can I concurrently operate on individual bits in a bitset? Say I have 10 threads, each has `threadId`. Can all threads concurrently set `bits[threadId] = value`?

Comment: No. A bitset is not a container.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[std::bitset::operator[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/operator[]/)

Data races

The bitset is accessed (neither the const nor the non-const versions modify the container).
The reference returned by the non-const version can be used to access or modify the bits in the bitset. Notice that modifying a single bit may have effects on an undetermined number of other bits in the bitset, thus rendering concurrent access/modification of different bits not thread-safe.